# I installed Ubuntu on ZFS, How to move to ext4 without a reinstall

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, zfs

As the title says, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Gave it my entire SSD (256GB) and I installed Atlas OS on my HDD but Windows on HDD is never a good idea to start with so I need to install Windows on my SSD and at the time I installed Ubuntu I did not know that I cannot shrink it .. So what is the best way to move to ext4 and leave some space for a Windows installation for work purposes? I spent so much time on my current configuration and I do not want to download, tweak and install all of that again as I have a limited internet subscription.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: I have already searched and the only question that is some how similar to mine is not answered yet

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the logical chain:

"Move from zfs to ext4" means changing your filesystem format.

Changing your filesystem format means that partition must be *reformatted*. No shortcut. No way around it.

Reformatting means all data on that partition will be destroyed. If that is your boot partition, then you must reinstall Ubuntu.

Preserving your configuration is why you have backups. You do not need to re-download everything if you have backups. After reinstallation, restore your data and customizations from your backup.

(Pro Tip: Test that you can restore from your backup *before* reformatting.)

Comment: Hello, I do understand that but I didn't find an effective way to backup my system as the tool I used to use does not support ZFS so what do you recommend me?